# Set value of input element using javascript and get the value using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here I have a form and input element:

cart.php

```
<form id="cartform" action="cart.php?action=update&pd=<?php echo $row['product_id'] ?>" name="form1" method="post">
<?php
    $query = "select * from cart where customer_id='$user' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);$payableamount = 0;$totalsavings = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $productid = $row['product_id'];
        $query2 = "select * from product where product_id='$productid'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
        while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {
?>
            <input tpe="text"  name="quantxt[]" id="quantxt" value="<?php echo $qty = $row['quantity']; ?>" onkeyup="showsubmit(<?php echo $row['cart_id'] ?>,<?php echo $row['product_id'] ?>)">
            <input type="text" name="s1" id="s1" value=""/>
            <input style="visibility:hidden;width:80px;border-radius:10px;background-color:green;border:none;padding:5px;color:white;"
               type="submit"
               name="sub_<?php echo $row['cart_id'] ?>"
               id="sub_<?php echo $row['cart_id'] ?>"
               value="UPDATE">
</table>    
</form>
```

and the javascript is:

```
<script>
    function showsubmit(id,prodid)
    {
        alert(id);
        alert(prodid);
        document.getElementById("sub_"+id).style.visibility ="visible";
        document.getElementById("s1").value = prodid;
        f = document.getElementById("s1").value;
        alert("product id is:"+f);
    }
</script>
```

when i am accessign the value of s1 element in cart2.php it gives nothing.
on next page s1 has no value,while i am expecting the value that is updated using javascript

```
$prod_id = $_POST['s1'];
echo "product id of clickable product is:".$prod_id."<br>";
```

Comment: Where does your while loop ends?

Comment: Incomplete code. No starting tag for `table`

Comment: are you getting values in  **alert(id);** and **alert(prodid);** ?

Comment: try to put this **<input type="text" name="s1" id="s1" value=""/>** outside of your loop as well as your submit button.

Comment: @Mit yeah It work fine by putting the s1 element outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
<input type="text" name="s1" id="s1" value=""/>
```

is inside a loop. can you make sure that the loop only has one row returning? because if not, then you're creating multiple elements with same `id` which javascript can not catch properly. `id` is supposed to be unique. in the case of multiple same ids it'll catch the first match and stop.